# GWT Error: RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run

Tags: java, gwt, dao, requestfactory, objectify

Everytime I launch my app I get the "RequestFactory Validation Tool must be run..." error even if listEmptyBoxes() is not executed. I already have file `requestfactory-apt-2.5.0-rc1.jar` on the annotation processing.

Any ideas? Below my code. Thanks.

**MyProject.java**

```
private void listEmptyBoxes() {
  BoxRequest boxRequest = requestFactory.boxRequest();
  boxRequest.listAllEmpty().fire(new Receiver<List<BoxProxy>>() {
    public void onSuccess(List<BoxProxy> response) { // List all phantom boxes
      Window.alert("Successful");
    }
  });
}
```

**BoxRequest.java**

```
@Service(value=BoxDao.class, locator=DaoServiceLocator.class)
public interface BoxRequest extends RequestContext {
    Request<List<BoxProxy>> listAllEmpty();
}
```

**BoxDao.java**

```
public class BoxDao extends ObjectifyDao<Box>{
    public List<Box> listAllEmpty() {
        Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
        Query<Box> q=ofy.query(Box.class).filter("title", null).filter("description", null);
        List<Box> results = q.list();
        return results;
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
04-may-2013 12:29:18 com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet doPost
GRAVE: Unexpected error
java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the com.gw.myProject.shared.myProjectRequestFactory RequestFactory type
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl.Deobfuscator$Builder.load(Deobfuscator.java:57)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.updateDeobfuscator(ResolverServiceLayer.java:43)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer.resolveRequestFactory(ResolverServiceLayer.java:176)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerDecorator.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerDecorator.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.getOrCache(ServiceLayerCache.java:233)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ServiceLayerCache.resolveRequestFactory(ServiceLayerCache.java:198)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:215)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.SimpleRequestProcessor.process(SimpleRequestProcessor.java:135)
    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet.doPost(RequestFactoryServlet.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:369)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doDirectServerRequest(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:352)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerServersFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerServersFilter.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
04-may-2013 12:29:19 com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From GWT 2.4, RequestFactory interfaces must be validated. So, have you carefully followed the [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation)? There you can find Eclipse/IntelliJ as well as Maven/Ant command line steps (checkout also in the comments).

The output of the validation tool is a class file called `"YourRequestFactoryName"DeobfuscatorBuilder.class` and is generated in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory, alongside `"YourRequestFactoryName".class`. So check for its presence and you'll be sure the validation tool has run (or remove it to be sure it will have to run).

Comment: I tried all of them but still getting the same error. Totally bogged down 
:(

Comment: I dont see that "YourRequestFactoryName"DeobfuscatorBuilder.class.

Answer (score 5):

Use following step -

1. Right click on project
2. Click on Java Compiler
3. Enable project specific setting
4. Select Annotation processing
5. Enable project specific setting
6. Select factory path
7. Add Jar -> Add requestfactory-apt.jar file -> OK -> OK
8. Done

Comment: You must add requestfactory-apt.jar to the WEB-INF\lib directory too.

Answer (score 1):

The [instruction](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation) now seems pretty old. To run `RequestFactory ValidationTool` with the latest `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.*:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.web.bindery</groupId>
            <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```